# Unable to return value in scoped for loop: jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, exacttarget

I have a problem in jQuery where the value in insert still returns null when running the code below. I'm running through Salesforce's Exact Target and also has a HTML Document and script doc, which also contains this code snippet below.

`var value = "Subscriptions are: ";
 var insert = null;`

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $("#lol").click(function() {
        if($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
            insert = "LOL";
            return insert;
        }
    })
};
value = value + insert;
```

In this instance, the data I receive in Exact target gives me "Subscription is: null". The checkbox would be checked and would not give me anything. I believe it could be a scoping problem?

Update:

```
$("#lol").click(function() {
        if($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
            console.log("lol");
            insert = "LOL";
        }
    });
```

will produce the same error

Comment: Note that when I delete the 'return insert' line, I still have the same bug.

Comment: what is the use of for loop here ?

Comment: Then your if statement must always be evaluating to false. Check to see it is correct. Most likely never reaches the return. I am hoping `value = value + insert;` is in a different function. Correct?

Comment: @HomemadeIcing its not clear at all what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Musa the rest of the code is currently on ExactTarget. I'm creating a preference center for a client using their software.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#lol").on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
        insert = "LOL";
    }
    value += insert;

    alert(insert); // Use `insert` here
});
```

1. `ID` should be `UNIQUE`
2. Don't need `for` to bind event
3. You cannot return from `event` handlers
4. Use `insert` inside the `event` handler

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is null, the function in the `click` will be called when you click the `$('#lol')` node, it will not executed if you do not click it.

Since the code running **too much faster** to you click the button, so it will always run `value = value + insert;` first before you click the `$('#lol')`